# Linker error when rebuilding C++-CLI project std::basic_string

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

I'm writing a C++ application in Visual Studio 2008. I've added a Windows Form to my project, enabled CLR support and added a line to instantiate the form.

Since doing this, I get a load of linker errors as follows:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall ... " (...)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Full error (anonymised):

```
1>Linking...
1>   Creating library C:\***.lib and object C:\***.exp
1>getProducts.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall ***::GetClassName(void)const " (?GetClassName@***@@UBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1>getProducts.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall ***::GetClassName(void)const " (?GetClassName@***@@MBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1>getProducts.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall ***::GetClassName(void)const " (?GetClassName@***@@MBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1>getProducts.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall ***::GetClassName(void)const " (?GetClassName@***@@MBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1>getProducts.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall ***::GetClassName(void)const " (?GetClassName@***@@MBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1>getProducts.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall ***::GetClassName(void)const " (?GetClassName@***@@MBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1>getProducts.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall ***::GetClassName(void)const " (?GetClassName@***@@MBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1>getProducts.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall ***::GetClassName(void)const " (?GetClassName@***@@MBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1>MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\***.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\***\BuildLog.htm"
1>getProducts - 10 error(s), 12 warning(s)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ========
```

Comment: Link Library Directories is set to "Yes". Is there any specific library I need to link?

Comment: Don't know I never worked on visual studio. Can you put the full error?

Comment: The problem is not with basic_string itself, but with another class having a `public: virtual` function that returns a `std::string`. Perhaps you forgot to implement this in some derived class? Or that function isn't linked to the executable?

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 does not support Managed C++. I therefore have retagged your question. (C++/CLI, which it does support, is a different language than "Managed C++" was)

Comment: (Also, removing your class name from the error message has obfuscated what the error is telling you. @Bo Persson has the right answer here.

Comment: `GetClassName` is your problem not string look at the declaration and implementation of this method in your code ... if you're still stuck post that method and details here and we'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Billy The only place I found in the internet with this signature is: 
http://www.xavierdupre.fr/hal_python/hal_python_help_html/hal_python_help_class_Object.html#GetClassName|outline
Do you use this library in your code?

Comment: @Selalerer: What? The OP's actual function signature isn't in this post. He has removed the identifying portions. (Furthermore, what does my code have to do with Matt's question?)

Comment: @Billy, sorry, meant to write @Matt and got confused because of your edit :-)

Comment: @selalerer: Ah. You're not going to find his signature because he removed the names: `__thiscall ***::GetClassName` <-- Note the ***s.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple user created files in your project, the error may occur because you are not declaring variables as extern or are including header files more than once. See the following website for the answer to your problem:

[www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/organizing-code-files-in-c-and-c-r1798](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/organizing-code-files-in-c-and-c-r1798)